# Eclipse PDT is freezing from time to time

Tags: eclipse, performance, helios

I am usign Eclipse PDT Helios and it sometimes freezes for 2-3 seconds even when working with small PHP files, like 10 rows without any includes in them or any complex statement that may cause a problem while parsing. My machine has more than 3GB RAM and I have setup the HEAP size to 990MB. The CPU is Intel E7500 2.9Ghz.

What could be the problem? It is annoying to work like that. I understand when it "thinks" for few seconds when opening large files like > 50KB but how about the small ones. It also freezes when I am making a change or I save the file. This is slowing the development process. I can have a freeze every min or 2 :(

Not sure if this is the right forum, but this is a programming problem connected with the IDE so I guess people here will not mind helping me if they can.

I am using Eclipse for PHP development with Subclipse installed and my working copies are on a server in our local network.

My current eclipse.ini is

`-startup

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar

--launcher.library

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810

-product

org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product

--launcher.defaultAction

openFile

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize

512M

-showsplash

org.eclipse.platform

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize

512m

--launcher.defaultAction

openFile

-vmargs

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.disablePrinting

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5

-Xms1024m

-Xmx1024m

-XX:PermSize=512m

-XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

Comment: Did you try tweaking the eclipse.ini? Like this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659

Comment: No I have not, but I am not sure what are the different settings for.

Comment: I have drop some of them in my INI but still have the problem. Let say that I add a style="" to some HTML DOM element. At the moment when I press the double quotes button the Eclipse start "thinking" which really makes me angry cause it happens all the time :(

Comment: Is it me or every one have problems editing big files with old type of coding PHP - mixture of PHP, HTML, CSS and JS? Any alternative IDEs that handle better such cases and support SVN as Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote an [article on speeding up PDT indexing](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/blogs/nwire/2010/09/five-tips-speeding-eclipse-pdt-and-nwire). It might help.

Comment: Yes I have one problem with the setup and it is described from as "Some store their workspace on a network drive". But this is the only way I can work now at my job. How big could be the impact of using network drive for storing the workplace. And I know that everythin on that drive is ecrypted/decrypted instantly which slows the process even more.

Comment: Well, this could be a very serious set back and it is probably the reason for the slowness that you experience. I'm not sure there's a solution for that at the moment.

Comment: I would only add, mount your db folder as tmpfs.  You can do this in ~/.bashrc if using linux.

Answer (score 2):

There are known issues with PDT 3.1 and eclipse 4.2 (juno).

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272

This is the solution:

Open a different perspective (for example java, but not php) and restart eclipse. Afterwards you can savely switch back to php perspective. Eclipse will have no (pdt induced) performance issues.

Also mentioned [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation_3.1.x)